# The no-records fetched processing in MySQL & PhP. Most optimal approach to handle?

Tags: php, mysql

Almost every dynamic db-driven webpage has the no-records fetched scenario to be addressed. I see several ways to do it, among them, the two obvious ones are:

a. First do a separate count(*) select on the same query and get the record court. If it returns a count of zero, do the no-record-found processing. Else, run the normal select and continue with the some-records-found processing-display-etc. You run the theoretical risk that between the first select and the second select, the record(s) which earlier resulted in a return of a non-zero count may get deleted.

b. Start PhP output buffering. Then output the table display headers. After doing the first fetch, if no record is found, then discard the PHP buffer, report no-record-found else do the some-records-found processing-display-etc. Here you are saving one select statement but there is a bit more coding with the buffers.

Question: What are other options available? Which is the better option?

Comment: For "a.", you could just use the "regular" query, and num_rows on the result?

Comment: All of the DB API's do have rowcount method. Basically: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1` `if($db->rowCount() > 0) { //display output } else { //tell no rows found }`

Comment: MySQL documentation states that this count is not reliable for select statements and a count(*) is recommended. It can be relied upon for updates and deletes.